# $Stab_{[1:0]}$ is a maximal subgroup of $SL_2(F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, projective-space

The full question:

> Let $SL_2(F)$ act naturally on the projective space $\mathbb{P}(F^2)$
>   over the field $F$ of at least 4 elements. Show that the stabilizer group $Stab_{[1:0]}$ of
>   the projective point $[1:0] \in \mathbb{P}(F^2)$ is a maximal subgroup
>   of $SL_2(F)$.

This was in the chapter of trying to prove the simplicity of $PSL_n(F)$, the projective special linear group defined as $SL_n(F)/Z(SL_n(F))$. I found this question very difficult and would appreciate some help. I also do not quite understand what they mean by "act naturally".

I am in my first year of learning abstract algebra, and haven't learned about Galois theory yet. This is the first time learning about projective spaces, but I think I understand that lines through the origins could be viewed as equivalence classes represented by points.

edit: Also, I would like to ask, what is the point of this question? Does it help us arrive at the conclusion that $PSL_n(F)$ is a simple group?

Comment: Acting "naturally" means by matrix multiplication. If you write the point $[x:y]$ as a column $\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$, then it's just $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax + by\\ cx + dy\end{pmatrix}$, i.e., the point $[ax + by : cx + dy]$. Where is this question from? It would be good to know what tools you have at your disposal. A good first step would be to characterize which matrices are in the stabilizer.

Comment: This problem was introduced in class. The instructor told us to use properties of doubly transitive groups. I also forgot to include that F has at least 4 elements (will edit).

Comment: It is clear the stabilizer is the group $B$ of upper triangular matrices thus you want to show that for any $M\not \in B$ (we can assume $M=\pmatrix{1&0\\ c&1}$) then $SL_2=\langle M,B\rangle$